# Background Image in Div on Right Border in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-6, png, background-position

Help

I try desperately to place a background image on the right border in a DIV in Internet Explorer 6.

No success so far.

This is my CSS:

```
.test
{
    width: 100px;
    border-right: red thin solid;
    border-top: red thin solid;
    border-left: red thin solid;
    border-bottom: red thin solid;


    background-position-x: 100%;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    background: url(roundcorner_righttile_11x11.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

the HTML:

```
<div class="test">
 text
</div>
```

The Div should in the End expand dynamically. The "100 px" is just for testing.

Maybe its because its an png file?

I am gratefull for any help.

Comment: Do you want to repeat the image horizontally?

Comment: No i want to repeat vertical.
Basically it should appear like a custom right Border made of a background image.

Comment: What is your error? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: The image dont appear on the right side of the DIV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.test
{
    width: 100px;
    border: red thin solid;    
    background: url(roundcorner_righttile_11x11.png) right top repeat-y;
}

<div class="test">
 text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.test
{
    width: 100px;
    border-right: red thin solid;
    border-top: red thin solid;
    border-left: red thin solid;
    border-bottom: red thin solid;

    background-position: right top;
    background: url(roundcorner_righttile_11x11.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```